# how to installing php-pecl-memcached

Tags: php, linux, memcached, redhat

for the life of me i cannot load yum install php-pecl-memcached

From the above i get the following messages:
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el6.rf.x86_64 has missing requires of fping
nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el6.rf.x86_64 has missing requires of perl(Net::SNMP)

When i skip broken i get
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
php-pecl-memcached-2.1.0-7.el6.art.x86_64 from atomic

I have spend a long time trying to get Memcached working i'm completely stumped.
I'm running CentOS 6.4 rhel

Any guidance is very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Install from source, solve dependency problems could take forever:
http://kb.liquidweb.com/install-memcached-on-centos-5/

Comment: Thanks for the link, i followed the instructions to the letter. I restarted httpd and now get the following server error.    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0    Would you know what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dependency problem due to conflicting yum repos. You can try removing recently added yum repos and trying. Or you could simply do a sudo pecl install memcached

Answer (score 0):

what all users who answer this question fail to explain to the novice is that there are two versions of memcache(d) there is the old memcache that needs extension=memcache.so to be placed in the php.ini file and there is the more recent one memcached which almost every tutorial I have read fails to explain to the novice how to set up memcached daemon. here is a link to one tutorial that should help fix that gap http://bookofzeus.com/articles/how-to-install-memcached-in-ubuntu/ after using this tutorial my Laravel app worked as sweet as a nut